# How to do regex renaming with Better File Rename (on Windows)

Tags: windows, regex

I can't find any documentation at all about renaming files using the regex functions in BFR.

I know I can use other apps, but I want to use this one.
http://www.publicspace.net/windows/BetterFileRename/

I simply want to swap some numbers at the tail of the filename with the text at the head...

like

```
/(.*)-(\d{6})/
```

and

```
$2 $1
```

Are there some docs or examples out there?

Thanks

Comment: Googled that site, products use strange, non standard syntax and definitions for regular expressions. IAC, try `/2` and `/1` in place of the backreferences you used.

Comment: Thanks. Will try. Apparently one also skips the surrounding // as well.

Comment: Yes, those aren't part of regex

Answer (score 0):

it's `\1`, `\2`, etc

The more recent versions of BFR actually show the column names as \1 and \2 to make things easier